# Migrated asp.net 2.0 site to 4.0 now throwing 401.1 - Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net site whose target framework is currently 2.0. I've recently moved it all to 4.0. Asp.net impersonation & Windows authentication is set to true. Its on a new app pool targeting the 4.0 framework using the same identity as the old app pool (NetworkService). When I browse to the migrated site I see a HTTP Error 401.1 - Unauthorized error. I'm entering the same domain credentials as before, it just doesn't seem to want to authenticate ... any ideas?

Comment: Check your Event Log for details and paste us the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I can login to the site just fine from a browser that is not on the box hosting the site ... up until now I had only tried logging in from a browser on the box itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ManagedPipeline to Classic on the AppPool. Otherwise, I suggested using application pool identities.

Application pool identities are virtual users created for each Application pool. You can then assign these users access to the folders in which their web apps reside.

See this tutrial for more info

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/